# VBScript Failed to filter non ascii characters

Tags: vbscript

I have this function:

```
Private Sub CheckParams(Values)    
    Dim Str, Ch

    If IsArray(Values) then
        Str = Join(Values, "")
    Else
        Str = Values
    End If

    For I = 1 To Len(Str)
         Ch = Asc(Mid(Str, I, 1))
         If Not ((Ch = 9) Or (Ch = 10) Or (Ch = 13) Or ((Ch > 31) And (Ch < 128))) Then
             SetError("script result contains illegal characters.")
         End If
    Next     
End Sub
```

This function throws error if the input value has characters that not on the list according to the If statement in the For loop. The problem is when my input value has Japanese characters, the validation is passed without error. I think the Asc() function, that use to return the ANSI code of the character, don't know how to handle the Japanese characters.
 What seems to be the problem here? 
 Is the Asc() function returns negative numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It is very similar to Ansgar's solution but instead MidB I used Mid with 1:
`ch = AscW(Mid(str, i, 1))`

Answer (score 1):

Kanji and Kana are most likely represented as 2-Byte Unicode characters, so you could try something like this:

```
ch = AscW(MidB(str, i, 2))
```

Comment: Is the AscW is good also for non-unicode? In other words, will it cover all?